# Предлагаю объединить метки “придаточное” и “придаточное-предложение”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “придаточное” и “придаточное-предложение”, сделав главной меткой “придаточное-предложение”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь! Всё сделал.